# Need help creating a share folder in Ubuntu 12.04 desktop

Tags: sharing

I'm a new Linux user. I want to create two sharing folders in my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop. One should be network password protected, another one should be non-password protected. Help with screenshots and videos would be useful..

Answer (score 0):

Samba would be your perfect solution. [Read more about Samba](http://wiki.samba.org/)

Watch this video: [Samba sharing in Ubuntu 12.4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8Lo20C19ao)